# Regex matcher - No match found from

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use regex to extract the values from a string and use them for the further processing.
The string I have is:

```
String tring =Format_FRMT: <<<$gen>>>(((valu e)))    <<<$gen>>>(((value 13231)))
<<<$gen>>>(((value 13231)))
```

Regex pattern I have made is:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<{3}\\$([\\w ]+)\\>{3}\\s?\\({3}([\\w ]+)\\){3}");
```

When I am running the whole program

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(tring);
    
   String[] try1 = new String[m.groupCount()];
            
    for(int i = 1 ; i<= m.groupCount();i++)
    {
        try1[i] = m.group(i);
        //System.out.println("group - i" +try1[i]+"\n");
    }
```

I am getting

> No match found

Where exactly this is going wrong?
My first aim is just to see whether I am able to get the values in the corresponding groups or not. And If that is working fine then I would like to use them for further processing.

Comment: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile\\<{3}\\$([\\w ]+)\\>{3}\\s?\\({3}([\\w ]+)\\){3});` ??? How??

Comment: As Avinash points out, your code is not syntactically valid and can't be compiled.  Start by removing most of your pattern and just start simple: eg just match three less-thans.  Does that work?  Then add the dollar-sign, and so on.

Comment: I missed a bracket, i have edited the question!

Comment: I used Expresso tool to check for my regex and it worked in that tool!

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: I would like to extract the "values" and "gen" without "$" symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an exaple of how to get all the values you need with `find()`:

```
String tring = "CHARDATA_FRMT: <<<$gen>>>(((valu e)))    <<<$gen>>>(((value 13231)))\n<<<$gen>>>(((value 13231)))";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<{3}\\$([\\w ]+)>{3}\\s?\\({3}([\\w ]+)\\){3}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(tring);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println("Gen: " + m.group(1) + ", and value: " + m.group(2));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uuSpBu)

Note that you do not have to escape `<` and `>` in Java regex.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, It worked partially.

If I change it to <{3}\\$[\\w ]+>{3}\\s?\\({3}([\\w ]+)\\){3}
I would get the first value in group(1). To get the other two value, I had to repeat the same expression twice or is there any other way to do that?

So that, group(1) give me valu e, group(2) give me value 13231 and group(3) gives me value 13231.

Thanks!

Comment: [`while` should handle](http://ideone.com/FeOP5W) that since those will be separate matches. The values you need will be in group 1 all the time. Capturing groups correspond the unescaped round brackets like `(...)`, if you have 1 there will be only `.group(1)`.

Comment: yes that is true, but is there any other meta character which can be used for this case?

Comment: No, I do not think so. If matches were consecutive you could use `\G`, but it is not necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

After you create the `Matcher` and before you reference its groups, you must call one of the methods that attempts the actual match, like `find`, `matches`, or `lookingAt`.  For example:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(tring);
if (!m.find()) return; // <---- Add something like this
String[] try1 = new String[m.groupCount()];
```

You should read the javadocs on the Matcher class to decide which of the above methods makes sense for your data and application. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: I know I could have done this for better error handling, but I wanted to know why I was getting the error. 

This was obvious though. Thanks.